# Custom Module in Magento not working

Tags: magento

The custom modules are not working, a 404 error is shown when trying to access the module via url, the module is correct as it works correctly on other machines (other people have tried the module on their magento) and it works fine, i think there might be some problem with my configuration settings or some other settings of magento. Please answer that how would the problem be solved?

Comment: Have you checked it's appearing and enabled in System > Configuration > Advanced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to solve this problem navigate to Admin->System->Permissions->User-> click "Reset Filter" and then flush your magento cache (Admin->System-> Cache Management-> Flush magento cache). Then logout and re-log to admin panel and navigate to your custom module it should be working by now